# Some event in ListBoxItem style are not firing

Tags: wpf, xaml, listviewitem

I have a listbox, binding on a collection of my custom object `MyNode`, and I want to set two events, `Drop` and `MouseRightButtonDown`. The listbox has custom control and style.

The style of my `ListBoxItem` looks like following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="pinnedListBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEF6FC"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#74B4E4"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="ListBoxItem_Drop"/>
        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I am using the listbox with a custom control like:

```
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Focusable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AllowDrop="True" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource pinnedListBoxStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyNode}">
                <local:MyItemTemplate/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The problem:

One of my two event handlers, which is `ListBoxItem_MouseRightButtonDown`, is never fired when I right click on any item. Another handler `ListBoxItem_Drop` is always fired as intended.

Could you have any ideas?

Comment: Try PreviewMouseRightButtonDown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Clemens's suggestion, using `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` or `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp` would both trigger my events.

I am now using:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" ...>
    ...
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
</Style>
```